# Is there a way to pre-define the python egg name programmatically?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, distutils, egg

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
kwargs = {"name": "foo",
                  "author": "",
                  "version": "1.0",
                  "ext_modules": Extension(name='util/helper/foo', sources=[]),}

setup(**kwargs)
```

I can only specify pacakge name and version, `foo-1.0.0`, from the code and `setup()` is adding stuff on top of it, like py version, cython version, platform, arch.

for example, the egg i get is `foo-1.0.0-py3.9-linux-x86_64.egg`

how do i get an egg name of `foo-1.0.0-py3.egg`?

Comment: Do note that the egg format has long since been superseded by the wheel format. Is there are particular reason why you need to work with an archaic format?

Comment: It's also not clear why you want to alter the [platform compatibility tag](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/platform-compatibility-tags/#platform-compatibility-tags). Those tags generally exist for a reason, and changing the tag won't change what ABI/platform your extension modules are compatible with.

Comment: @Brian61354270 i run wheel convert on the egg. i use egg because wheel doesnt support excluding .py

Comment: @Brian61354270 i have a diff way of ensuring that. no need to do it at the egg level for simpler workflows